# how to submit on select_month or select_year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form:

```
= form_tag payments_path, method: :get do
  = select_month(@start_date, {use_two_digit_numbers: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'})
  = select_year(@start_date, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => DateTime.now.year, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'})
  = submit_tag("Search", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

**How can I abandon the submit_tag and submit whenever I select a month or a year?**

Comment: You'll want to use javascript (jquery) for this and call a submit form script everytime the field changes however it's not very user friendly to ask for a month & year but submit the form as soon as they enter one of the fields so I'd recommend a script that checks for both fields entered and submits.

Comment: Take a look at this gem https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails. Useful datepicker with event changeDate (so you can trigger a 'click' to the search button via javascript every time the date changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `onchange: this.form.submit()` will do the trick for you.

```rb
= form_tag payments_path, method: :get do
  = select_month(@start_date, {use_two_digit_numbers: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month', onchange: 'this.form.submit()'})
  = select_year(@start_date, {:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => DateTime.now.year, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year', onchange: 'this.form.submit()'})
```